# Strange outcome when testing identity with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, identity

I have a question about identity testing using numpy. Please, attend at this piece of code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: UTF-8



import numpy

data = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]])
```

This returns False, of course

```
row1 = numpy.array([5, 1, 2])

print row1 in data
```

This should give false as well, but because it starts with one element of the rows of data (4), it returns True.

```
row2 = numpy.array([4, 8, 9])
print row2 in data
```

Somebody can explain the reason in depth?

Thank you all for your time!